# How to work with DrawerLayout in xml Android studio

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

Hi i know this question is too silly but this really matters for the application. Working with xml is the big deal. I am facing lots of problems.

Its not allowing me just to drag and drop the things, When i do, its placing in some other position.

I can able to manage inside Relative layout but **DrawerLayout** I can't able to do what i want.  Here is my **XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <!--  -->
        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

             android:id="@+id/fragment"
             android:name="corp.msf.com.facebookconnect.MainFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have Toolbar above and below that i want the fragment to come. But fragment occupies all the place ( overlaps on toolbar ) . How can i specify and how can i work with xmls easily. Any help welcomed. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  for your toolbar and fragment.

Set the orientation of linear layout as vertical as below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/fragment"
             android:name="corp.msf.com.facebookconnect.MainFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```